# Bash Syntax for Using GREP to Extract Text from File and Store in an Array

Tags: bash, grep, aix, array, command-substitution

I have recently upgraded from `bash 4.2.46` to `bash version 4.2.50`

I had a script with the line:

`mapfile -t my_array  < <(grep ${ID} -w /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f 1,4,5)`

where ID is an arbitrary integer we'd like to look for in the file `passwd` and then load all results into an array.

that used to work but now throws an error

```
usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
```

can anyone explain how to work around this depreciation? I have attempted using `sed` and `awk` however the issue seems to be the format of my output redirection.

the text file `passwd` looks like this
`name:garbageData:garbageData:ID:password`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get that error if you executed the script with ksh instead of with bash; either the sh-bang header line incorrectly points to ksh, or it points to /bin/sh which is ksh on AIX, or you're explicitly calling it as `ksh /the/script`.

ksh does not support `mapfile` nor with versions prior to ksh93t+, the `<( ...)` process substitution syntax **when used as the target of a redirection**, such as `<`. Clarification provided by [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas).

Fix the sh-bang line to call bash (or explicitly invoke bash instead of ksh, if that's the case).

Additionally, the `grep` command is complaining because you've put an argument before all of the options; rearrange the grep to be:

```
grep -w "${ID}" /etc/passwd
```

(also quoting the variable expansion).

Comment: Thank you for the response; I am currently using #!/bin/bash as my shebang line and upon further investigation I believe I am using it correctly. However your solution lead me down a rabbit hole explaining the difference between "bash /the/script" and "./script" which has yielded another error, so I'll update the question :)

Comment: Is /bin/bash a link to /bin/ksh, for some reason?

Comment: I do not believe so as my /bin directory contains both ksh and bash. Is there another definitive way I can tell?

Comment: @CyberStems run `ls -i /bin/bash /bin/ksh*` and see if the numbers on the left are the same; or `ls -l /bin/bash` and see if it's a symlink.

Comment: in the first command the numbers differ, and the second command outputs /bin/bash -> ../opt/freeware/bin/bash so I don't think it is a symlink. Once again your extensive help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Since the inode numbers differ; /bin/bash is not a (hard) link to ksh; the `/bin/bash -> ../opt/freeware/bin/bash` indicates that /bin/bash is a symlink to (another) bash. Hopefully calling `/opt/freeware/bin/bash  --version` outputs "bash" text and version?

Comment: It does! The output is: GNU bash, version 4.2.50(1)

Comment: @CyberStems: Alright, so with the `grep` fix and the correct sh-bang line, you should be much further along...?